# How can I map a json object of tree and set it in separate variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Really hard to explain, but I'll do my best. So I've got a `JSON` data used on a `JqTree` and I'm trying to get which are the `parents` and the `children` and put them in little blocks.

**My Tree**:

[image]

**and its `data` AKA structure**:

```
var data = [
  {"name":"node1","id":1,"is_open":true,"children":[
    {"name":"child2","id":2},
    {"name":"child2","id":3},
    {"name":"child1","id":4}
  ]},
  {"name":"node1","id":5,"is_open":true,"children":[
    {"name":"child2","id":6}
  ]}
];
```

***What I want to do is to put them into variables, like these:***

variables `dad` and `son` and their `id`s

`dad = 1 son = 2
 dad = 2 son = 3` and so on.

Notice that `dad = 2` is also the `son = 2`

Thus, my tree would be:

`dad = 1  son = 2 
 dad = 1  son = 3
 dad = 1  son = 4
 dad = 5  son = 6`

I need it this way because I'll send it using `AJAX` like this:
`data:dad+"&"+son`, and if you check my code you will notice that this will be sent when the user changes the structure with the cursor, **so it will be always one **dad** and one **son****, thus, no array needed.

- **Why**:

I need to send it that way because I'm using a shitty and limited language on the server side (it's not mine)

- **My Tree explained:**

The original data will in the future be sent by this shitty server like this `dad = 1 & son = 2`, then I will do "simply" the reverse.
My server compares the original `data` with the new one and gives me the difference that I should transform into that way again and send it using ajax.

**Right now, as you can see, I'm sending only the "difference" `POSITIONS`**.

```
$('#tree1').bind(
    'tree.move',
    function(event) {
      data = $(this).tree('toJson');
      event.preventDefault();
      // do the move first, and _then_ POST back.
      event.move_info.do_move();
      console.log("New Structure" + $(this).tree('toJson'));
      POSITIONS = $(this).tree('toJson');

      POSITIONS = getDiff(data, POSITIONS);
      alert("Difference\n\n" + POSITIONS);

      $.post('http://localhost:8080/JqTree/Hello', {
        tree: POSITIONS
      });
      alert("done");
    }
);
```

Thank you so much for reading this far.

**This is my code**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var POSITIONS;
  //Mandar o response aqui no data
  var data = [{
    label: 'node1',
    id: 1,
    children: [{
      label: 'child1',
      id: 2
    }, {
      label: 'child2',
      id: 3
    }, {
      label: 'child2',
      id: 6
    }]
  }, {
    label: 'node2',
    id: 4,
    children: [{
      label: 'child3',
      id: 5
    }]

  }];



  $('#tree1').tree({
    data: data,
    autoOpen: false,
    dragAndDrop: true
  });


  function getDiff(a, b) {
    var diff = (isArray(a) ? [] : {});
    recursiveDiff(a, b, diff);
    return diff;
  }

  function recursiveDiff(a, b, node) {
    var checked = [];

    for (var prop in a) {
      if (typeof b[prop] == 'undefined') {
        addNode(prop, '[[removed]]', node);
      } else if (JSON.stringify(a[prop]) != JSON.stringify(b[prop])) {
        // if value
        if (typeof b[prop] != 'object' || b[prop] == null) {
          addNode(prop, b[prop], node);
        } else {
          // if array
          if (isArray(b[prop])) {
            addNode(prop, [], node);
            recursiveDiff(a[prop], b[prop], node[prop]);
          }
          // if object
          else {
            addNode(prop, {}, node);
            recursiveDiff(a[prop], b[prop], node[prop]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function addNode(prop, value, parent) {
    parent[prop] = value;
  }

  function isArray(obj) {
    return (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]');
  }

  console.log("Original Structure" + $('#tree1').tree('toJson'));

  $('#tree1').bind(
    'tree.move',
    function(event) {
      data = $(this).tree('toJson');
      event.preventDefault();
      // do the move first, and _then_ POST back.
      event.move_info.do_move();
      console.log("New Structure" + $(this).tree('toJson'));
      POSITIONS = $(this).tree('toJson');

      POSITIONS = getDiff(data, POSITIONS);
      alert("Difference\n\n" + POSITIONS);

      $.post('http://localhost:8080/JqTree/Hello', {
        tree: POSITIONS
      });
      alert("done");
    }
  );
});
```

```css
#navdata {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  flex: 1;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}
#navgrid {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: solid 1px #79B7E7;
  background-color: white;
}
#header {
  background-color: #79B7E7;
  width: 99.6%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: 1px;
}
.jqtree-element {
  background-color: white
  /*#DDEBF7*/
  ;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 23px;
  color: red;
}
.jqtree-tree .jqtree-title {
  color: black;
}
ul.jqtree-tree {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
ul.jqtree-tree,
ul.jqtree-tree ul.jqtree_common {
  list-style: none outside;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.jqtree-tree ul.jqtree_common {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 0;
  /*border-left:20px solid #DDEBF7;*/
}
ul.jqtree-tree li.jqtree-closed > ul.jqtree_common {
  display: none;
}
ul.jqtree-tree li.jqtree_common {
  clear: both;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.jqtree-tree .jqtree-toggler {
  color: #325D8A;
}
ul.jqtree-tree .jqtree-toggler:hover {
  color: #3966df;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.jqtree-tree .jqtree-title.jqtree-title-folder {
  margin-left: 0;
}
span.jqtree-dragging {
  color: #fff;
  background: #79B7E7;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2px 8px;
}
ul.jqtree-tree li.jqtree-selected > .jqtree-element,
ul.jqtree-tree li.jqtree-selected > .jqtree-element:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BEE0F5), to(#79B7E7));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://sistema.agrosys.com.br/sistema/labs/tree.jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sistema.agrosys.com.br/sistema/labs/jqtree.css">
  <script src="http://sistema.agrosys.com.br/sistema/labs/jquery-cookie/src/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="navgrid">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="tree1">
      <ul class="jqtree_common jqtree-tree">
        <li class="jqtree_common jqtree-folder">
          <div class="jqtree-element jqtree_common">
            <a class="jqtree_common jqtree-toggler">â–¼</a>
            <span class="jqtree_common jqtree-title jqtree-title-folder">node1</span>
          </div>
          <ul class="jqtree_common ">
            <li class="jqtree_common">
              <div class="jqtree-element jqtree_common">
                <span class="jqtree-title jqtree_common">child2</span>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="jqtree_common">
              <div class="jqtree-element jqtree_common">
                <span class="jqtree-title jqtree_common">child1</span>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="jqtree_common jqtree-folder">
          <div class="jqtree-element jqtree_common">
            <a class="jqtree_common jqtree-toggler">â–¼</a>
            <span class="jqtree_common jqtree-title jqtree-title-folder">node2</span>
          </div>
          <ul class="jqtree_common ">
            <li class="jqtree_common">
              <div class="jqtree-element jqtree_common">
                <span class="jqtree-title jqtree_common">child3</span>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do your sample data points all align with each other? Would be helpful to understand this better if it all matched.

Comment: Why don't you just POST your tree as JSON rather than trying to flatten it? WHy do you keep calling `$(this).tree('toJson')` repeatedly after you have already made this serialization on the first line of your function? Other than that, I am not really clear on sure example.  For example, where does `dad=3` come from?

Comment: @MikeBrant it's really raw right now, and it's just an example, I need to flatten it because the real tree is gonna have more than 300 branches. the `dad = 3` will be created just after I compared the two structures the old and the new one, so if the user changed from  `[{ A { B } { C } }]` to `[{ A { B { C } }  }]` I will have to send `dad = B & son = C` because only `B` and `C` were changed. `B` and `C` are the `id`s

Comment: @Jacob I edited my question, I hope it's clearer, if not, tell me :) thanks for stopping to comment.

Comment: That's a bit clearer. It's still not clear what you mean by "Notice that dad = 2 is also the son = 2" since the data doesn't seem to match that.

Comment: @Calne  I would say that if your tree structure has 300 branches, that would be even more reason not to flatten out the tree and having to deal with the complexity of reassembling it.  It is much easier to take that tree-like data structure, serialize it for transport and then deserialize it back into tree-like structure.